# How can I use remote desktop to login as the same user as the Host? [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

What I want to do is this:
I have a laptop and a desktop, both running Win 10 (laptop's is Home and Desktop's is pro)
Now let's say I'm installing a game in my desktop and I want to see the progress from my laptop. When I try remote desktop from my laptop, I login as "Other user" and I cant see any window open. Even using "RD Client" app from my android phone has the same issue.
Now how can I create a RD connection so as to see what's going on in my desktop at the current time??
PS I Installed RDPWrapper if that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just login as yourself [the user you are using to do that install etc].

It will close the current session on the remote screen & hand it to you instead, with everything still running.

When finished, it will leave the remote machine with a lock screen, but everything still running. Log back in to see everything just as you left it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there no way to "Mirror" whatever is happening in my desktop screen, on my laptop, and still being able to use my desktop, using RDP? It's useful if i want to monitor what the person using my desktop is doing, without letting him/her know

Comment: No, not possible - the full server version can do it, but  not the standard. Even then you cannot use it to spy, it's clearly announced.